# How to prove $(\phi-1)(\phi-2)...(\phi-p) = \sqrt{5} + p\left(\frac{1}{2}+A\sqrt{5}\right) \bmod p^2$?

Tags: number-theory, finite-fields, fibonacci-numbers, quadratic-residues, stirling-numbers

We consider the solution of $x^2=x+1$ and denote them as $\phi=\frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5}),\bar\phi=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$.
Suppose $\phi \not\in \mathbb{F}_p$. In other words, $\sqrt{5} \not \in \mathbb{F}_p\Leftrightarrow p = \pm 2 \bmod 5$. Arbitrary element of $\mathbb{F}_p(\phi)$, $a$ and $b$ satisfies $ab=0\Leftrightarrow a=0 \lor b=0$. From Fermat's little theorem and factor theorem, 
$$(x-1)(x-2)...(x-p) = x^p -x \bmod p .$$
Then, put $x=\phi$. Since Frobenius map,$x \mapsto x^p$, transfer $\phi$ to conjugate of itself, $\bar\phi$,
\begin{align}
&(\phi-1)(\phi-2)...(\phi-p) = \bar\phi -\phi \bmod p \\
\Leftrightarrow &(\phi-1)(\phi-2)...(\phi-p) = \sqrt{5}\bmod p
\end{align}
Then, what about $(\phi-1)(\phi-2)...(\phi-p) \bmod p^2$?
Surprisingly, this can be expressed as 
$$(\phi-1)(\phi-2)...(\phi-p) = \sqrt{5} + p\left(\frac{1}{2}+A\sqrt{5}\right) \bmod p^2$$
empirically (I verify this rule by a code here [ideone](https://ideone.com/pw0QsN). $a$ and $b$ of the output corresponds to $a=\frac{1}{2}p$ and $b=1+pA$). I cannot find the rule for $A$, but everytime the coeffieicnt of $p$ of $\mathbb{F}_p$ is $\frac{1}{2}$ at $\bmod p^2$.

How to prove this rule?

UPDATE:

\begin{align}
&(\phi-0)(\phi-1)...(\phi-(p-1)) = \sqrt{5} + p\left(-2+A\sqrt{5}\right) \bmod p^2 \\
&(\phi-1)(\phi-2)...(\phi-(p+0)) = \sqrt{5} + p\left(2^{-1}+A\sqrt{5}\right) \bmod p^2 \\
&(\phi-2)(\phi-3)...(\phi-(p+1)) = \sqrt{5} + p\left(-2^{-1}+A\sqrt{5}\right) \bmod p^2 \\
\end{align}

Comment: Can you share a table of $A$ for some values of $p$?

Comment: Yes. https://ideone.com/pw0QsN

Comment: It's not hard to see that all the claims in the update are equivalent - for instance, the first two differ by $p(\phi-1)\dots(\phi-(p-1))\equiv p(\phi^p-\phi)/\phi\pmod{p^2}$.

Comment: Wojowu> Thank you. I agree all of the formula in the update are equivalent.

Comment: It can be seen that the result is implied by the following simpler conditions: For a prime $p$, let $ax+b$ be the remainder when dividing $\prod_{i=1}^p (x-i)$ by $x^2-x-1$. Then for $p>2$, one has $p^2|(a+2b-p)/2$. Furthermore if $p\equiv 2,3~({\rm mod~}5)$, then $p|(a+2)$.

Comment: Yes. I consider $\prod (x-i) \bmod x^2-x-1$ originally.

Comment: I get answer at Math Overflow [link](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344667/how-to-prove-phi-1-phi-2-phi-p-sqrt5-p-left-frac12a-sqrt?noredirect=1#344680).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question already get answer at 
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344667/how-to-prove-phi-1-phi-2-phi-p-sqrt5-p-left-frac12a-sqrt?noredirect=1#344680